# Problem listening for a node event emitter inside a server sent events stream (server creates a listener for every active user)

Tags: node.js, express

I have a function set up to poll a third party API and I'm using server sent events together with an event emitter to deliver updates to user clients:

```
// server.js
const interval = 60 * 60 * 1000;
setInterval(async () => {
  const toStream = await poll();
  app.emit('update', toStream);
}, interval);
```

```
    // sync.js
    router.get('/stream', [auth], (req, res) => {
      const user = req.user.id;
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Content-Encoding': 'none',
        Connection: 'keep-alive'
      });
      req.app.on('update', toStream => {
        if (toStream.some(toStreamE => toStreamE.user === user)) {
          res.write('event: message\n');
          res.write(
            `data: ${JSON.stringify(
              toStream.find(toStreamE => toStreamE.user === user)
            )}\n`
          );
          res.write('\n\n');
        }
      });
    });
```

And it works, when you have a couple of users. The problem is that the server creates a listener for every client connection, and as soon as you have a dozen of those, the limit for listeners for a single event is hit, and subsequent connections to the stream are dropped. My question is, how do I achieve the same functionality, but with a single listener? Where am I supposed to put it? I've also tried referencing app in a different way, but it didn't help:

```
app.use('/api/sync', require('./routes/sync')(app));
```

EDIT: Added the answer to my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was tricky, but I figured it out. But first it's worth mentioning that node doesn't actually limit the number of listeners despite throwing a warning, like I originally thought. Anyway, for this to work I created a separate module containing an object that hosts the emitter, plus an array that tracks your connections to the SSE stream:

```
// emitter.js

const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

const emitterObj = {
  emitter: new EventEmitter(),
  connections: [],
  emitFunc: function (ev, data) {
    this.emitter.emit(ev, data);
  },
  addCon: function (res) {
    if (this.connections.some(resE => resE.req.user.id === res.req.user.id)) {
      this.connections.splice(
        this.connections.findIndex(
          resE => resE.req.user.id === res.req.user.id
        ),
        1,
        res
      );
    } else {
      this.connections.push(res);
    }
    const conTimeout = 65 * 60 * 1000;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.connections.splice(
        this.connections.findIndex(
          resE => resE.req.user.id === res.req.user.id
        ),
        1
      );
    }, conTimeout);
  }
};

emitterObj.listenFunc = emitterObj.emitter.on('update', toStream => {
  emitterObj.connections.map(resE => {
    if (toStream.some(streamE => streamE.user === resE.req.user.id)) {
      const data = toStream.find(streamE => streamE.user === resE.req.user.id);
      resE.write('event: message\n');
      resE.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n`);
      resE.write('\n\n');
    }
  });
});

module.exports = emitterObj;
```

In my implementation, I'm limiting users to a single concurrent connection to the stream, though it can be changed if need be. Also, their connection has to be removed from the array eventually, otherwise it will keep growing and slowing everything down, I chose to do this after 65 minutes. 
In the listener, I'm going over the array of connections and send users updates if there are any. Of course, now you have to use the same emitter in server.js as well:

```
// server.js

const emitterObj = require('./emitter');

// ...

const interval = 60 * 60 * 1000;
setInterval(async () => {
  const toStream = await poll();
  emitterObj.emitFunc('update', toStream);
}, interval);
```

The sync route looks like this now:

```
// sync.js

router.get('/stream', [auth], (req, res) => {
  emitterObj.addCon(res);
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Content-Encoding': 'none',
    Connection: 'keep-alive'
  });
  emitterObj.listenFunc;
});
```

Hope it helps someone.

EDIT: Apparently, req.on('close') helps a lot in my case. I've added it to remove the connection (still have a timer in place in case it doesn't fire for some reason). Also, the client should be pinged periodically so it doesn't drop the connection. The biggest problem here is that Firefox doesn't restore it if that happens, unlike Chrome. My additions:

```
  const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    res.write(`event: ping\n`);
    res.write(`data: keep connection alive\n\n`);
  }, 60 * 1000);
  req.on('close', () => {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    emitterObj.deleteCon(req);
  });



  deleteCon: function (req) {
    if (this.connections.some(resE => resE.req.user.id === req.user.id)) {
      this.connections.splice(
        this.connections.findIndex(resE => resE.req.user.id === req.user.id),
        1
      );
    }
  }
```